# Add passThroughAttribute to SelectItem

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2.2

If I want to add passThroughAttributes to some of the `options` of a `select`-element I can use [f: passThroughAttribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/f/passThroughAttribute.html) as child-component of [f:selectItem](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/f/selectItem.html).

But normally I'm using a `List` of [SelectItems](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/SelectItem.html) to generate the options. In contrast to  `UiComponent` `SelectItem` does not have a method [getPassThroughAttributes](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.2/javadocs/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getPassThroughAttributes%28%29).

Anybody knows a reason why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because it doesn't have a `Renderer` associated. In case of `<f:xxx>` components (taghandlers and models) it's instead the closest parent `<h:xxx>` component (`UIComponent` instances) or, if any, the closest nested `<h:xxx>` component which does have a `Renderer` associated. The `Renderer` is namely the one responsible for generating all HTML output, including passthrough attributes. Note that the passthrough attributes have in such case to be set on the `<h:xxx>` component itself.

If you intend to control/manipulate the attributes of generated `<option>` elements, then you can't go around creating a custom `Renderer`, if necessary based on the standard `Renderer` implementation.